# Can't grep a base 64 img with the jquery.html() method

Tags: jquery, base64, tinymce-4

My website uses the version 4 of tiny mce. I use the drag and drop facility to include images in the editor. Including works fine and the editor contains a base 64 image in line.
When I want to extract the content of the editor to save it in a database I get the start of the content except the img and all the stuff that follows.

The content of the editor seen with the 'code' option:

`` <p>Saisissez votre texte ICI...<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA.........rkJggg==" alt="" />` texte à nouveau</p> ``

Part of the script:

```
function ecrire_offre(rang) {
    var contenu = $('#editor').html();
...
```

The result seen with the firefox debugger :

```
contenu : "Saisissez votre texte ICI..."
```

Did somebody can explain me what happen and how to fix it ?

Comment: Use the tinyMCE API to get the current editor content

Comment: I use 'var contenu = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent(); ' and it works fine. It was so simple. Sorry for such a basic question.